# Keras Functional API: LTSM returns a 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I'm stack and I need the wisdom of stackoverflow.

I have a two inputs neural network implemented in Keras using the *Functional API*, the input shapes are:

```
X.shape, X_size.shape, y.shape

((123, 9), (123, 2), (123, 9, 10))
```

So, my problem is I want to get output shape from LSTMs have 3-D shape, in order to use my **y** tensor. I know, I can reshape my **y** to 2-D shape, but I want to use it as a 3-D array.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers
from keras import Input

# first input 

list_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='li')
embedded_list = layers.Embedding(100,90)(list_input)
encoded_list = layers.LSTM(4,  name = "lstm1")(embedded_list)

# second input 
size_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='si')
embedded_size = layers.Embedding(100,10)(size_input)
encoded_size = layers.LSTM(4, name = "lstm2")(embedded_size)

# concatenate
concatenated = layers.concatenate([encoded_size, encoded_list], axis=-1)

answer = layers.Dense(90, activation='sigmoid', name = 'outpuy_layer')(concatenated)


model = Model([list_input, size_input], answer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=[f1])
```

Model summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
si (InputLayer)                  (None, None)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
li (InputLayer)                  (None, None)          0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_16 (Embedding)         (None, None, 10)      1000        si[0][0]                         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_15 (Embedding)         (None, None, 90)      9000        li[0][0]                         
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm2 (LSTM)                     (None, 4)             240         embedding_16[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm1 (LSTM)                     (None, 4)             1520        embedding_15[0][0]               
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)      (None, 8)             0           lstm2[0][0]                      
                                                                   lstm1[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
outpuy_layer (Dense)             (None, 90)            810         concatenate_8[0][0]              
====================================================================================================
Total params: 12,570
Trainable params: 12,570
Non-trainable params: 0
```

One more time, the question is:

**How to get output shape from LSTMs like (None, None, None/10)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras ignores every timestep output except the last one by default, which creates a 2D array. To get a 3D array (meaning you get the output of every timestep), instantiate the layer with `return_sequences` set to `True`. In your case for example:

```
encoded_list = layers.LSTM(4,  name = "lstm1", return_sequences=True)(embedded_list)
```